# null cookie in Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm writing a middleware to filter a request based on its cookies, but I get a null cookie.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    var_dump ($request->cookie("cookie_name"); //<------- null
    return $next($request);
}
```

Is this the right function to get a cookie from middleware? Why is null, if cookie exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel is encrypting cookies, so I had to add an exception to encrypted cookies in `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies\`

```
protected $except = [
    'cookie_name'
];
```